# Set color style using data template according to data object property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, datatemplate

I have a data object which contains a string message and a status enum.
my goal is to set the color of a textblock according to status value.

the data template:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type interfaces_general1:AnalogPinData}" x:Key="analogSignalTestTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Width="135"  Text="{Binding Path=ThresholdDescriptor.Message}" Style="{StaticResource colorfulTextBlockStyleAnalogPin}" />
            </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

the style

```
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" BasedOn="{StaticResource emphasizableTextBlock}" x:Key="colorfulTextBlockStyleAnalogPin">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource /*need to get here to a data object property*/}, Path=??}" Value="Info">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource= /*need to get here to a data object property*/, Path=Text}" Value="Warning">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Orange" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

how can i do a binding to the status proerty

the data object is:

```
public class AnalogPinData
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Pin information
    /// </summary>
    [PublicAPI]
    public AnalogPin Pin { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Threshold definition information
    /// </summary>
    [PublicAPI]
    public ThresholdDescriptor ThresholdDescriptor { get; set; }
}

public class ThresholdDescriptor
{
    public Range Range { get; set; }

    [PublicAPI]
    public StatusIndicator Status { get; set; }

    [PublicAPI]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

I need the Message and Status props to set in  the binding.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the instance of the template's data type is the `DataContext` of the `DataTemplate` and the `TextBlock` is an element in this template, the `TextBlock` will implicitly inherit this `DataContext` i.e. the `DataContext` of `TextBlock` is the instance of `AnalogPinData`.

Thus binding to the `TextBlock` element's `DataContext` solves the problem:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
  <Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ThresholdDescriptor.Status}" Value="Info">
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
    </DataTrigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Alternatively define the triggers directly in the DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type interfaces_general1:AnalogPinData}" x:Key="analogSignalTestTemplate">
  <TextBlock x:Name="StatusMessageTextBlock" Text="{Binding Path=ThresholdDescriptor.Message}" />

  <DataTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ThresholdDescriptor.Status}" Value="Info">
      <Setter TargetName="StatusMessageTextBlock" Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
    </DataTrigger>
  </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```